# Trying to create table with 3 foreign keys on ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create database where I have 3 tables to keep the data and the forth table to store the actual operations that processes the data. On the operations table I am using 3 foreign keys that referred to the other table but somehow I am able to create the table only with 2 foreign keys but once I add the third foreign key I get an error:

The Sql code for the operations table:

```
CREATE TABLE Operations
(
   operation_Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   User_Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_user_ID REFERENCES Users (User_Id),
   course_Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_course_ID REFERENCES Courses (Course_Id)
   college_Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_college_ID REFERENCES Colleges (college_Id)
)
```

and the tables with the relationships: 
[image]

The Error

[image]

Note, Once I receive the error it point at the college_Id on the operations table

Comment: You need to create the reference tables before defining the foreign key relationships.

Comment: Missing `,` after `... REFERENCES Courses (Course_Id)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sticky-bit said, There is a missing `,` in your query right after `Courses (Course_Id)` see the correct one :

```
CREATE TABLE Operations
(
   operation_Id AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   User_Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_user_ID REFERENCES Users (User_Id),
   course_Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_course_ID REFERENCES Courses (Course_Id),
   college_Id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_college_ID REFERENCES Colleges (college_Id)
)
```